# Access variable in another method from static method in same class

Tags: php, class, oop

I am looking for the best/correct way to do the following:

```
myClass::getSomething('stuff');

class myClass
{

    public static function getSomething($var) {

        $obj = new static();
        $obj->var = $var;

        $obj->somethingElse();

    }

    public function somethingElse() {

        // I need to access $obj->var in here

    }

}
```

Do I pass `$obj` to `somethingElse()`, is that the right way?

Comment: The `getSomething` method looks like it belongs to a factory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$obj` is an instance of `myClass`: It has - among others - a method `somethingElse()` and you just added a property `$var`.

So in your method you can access the property directly:

```
public function somethingElse() {

    $the_contents_of_var = $this->var;

}
```

Comment: I'm clearly having a bad day. I swear I did that and received the error `Using $this when not in object context`. But I just tried it again and it has worked!! Think I may call it a day...

Comment: @superphonic Perhaps you did a `self::somethingElse()` before, it looks a bit confusing (to me at least...) to have a static method to construct an object in the same class as the object that you are constructing :-)

Comment: Well when you put it like that :-)